# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to do seller can edit and update product

this is ProductController

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('product.edit', compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product-> title = $request-> title;
        $product-> description = $request-> description;
        $product-> price = $request-> price;

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $file = $request-> file('image');
            $filename = time().'.'.$file-> getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('/images');
            $file-> move($location, $filename);
            $oldImage = $product->image;
            \Storage::delete($oldImage);
            $product-> image= $filename;
        }
        $product-> save();

        return back();
    }
```

this is edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('product.update', $product->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{method_field('put')}} 
[...]

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

this is web.php

```
Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index');//seller view all product

Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@create'); //seller create new product
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store'); //store in database

Route::get('/edit/{id}','ProductController@edit'); // seller edit post
Route::post('','ProductController@update')->name('product.update'); //seller update
```

when i click submit button for update 
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.  show up

how i can fix it? PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try again please;

```
Route::put('edit/{id}','ProductController@update')->name('product.update');
```

and

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update', ["id" => $product->id]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('put') }}
[...]

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Comment: kindly, update your previous answer, if it does not solve the problem

Comment: what if the seller want to delete the product how i can do that

<form action="{{ route('product.destroy', ["id" => $product->id]) }}" method="post">
                  {{csrf_field()}}
                  {{method_field('DELETE')}} 
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>



Route::delete('','ProductController@destroy')->name('product.destroy');//seller delete product

i try this but error

Answer (score 1):

You should use PUT in route;

```
Route::put('','ProductController@update')->name('product.update');
```

And not produc.update not except product->id

```
<form action="{{route('product.update')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{method_field('put')}} 
[...]

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: @user12149659 Just change the form action route to `<form action="{{route('product.update', $product->id)}}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `id` parameter in your form request like below:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update', $product->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('put') }}
[...]

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

And then modify your controller method to be as below:

```
Route::put('edit/{id}','ProductController@update')->name('product.update');
```

This is because your controller method is expecting an `id` to be passed through in the request but isn't actually receiving one, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

if you have nothing wrong with routes or view files such as forgot to put @method('PUT')
then once try running "php artisan optimize" command, it helped me it clears all config and route cache.