# Laravel Inertiajs redirect to_route: The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.)

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am sending a put request to /admin/permissions/{permission} to update the permission and getting an error :

```
Symfony\ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

PHP 8.1.10
Laravel 9.38.0
InertiaJs 0.6.3
```

Regarding the update method, I should be redirected to_route('admin.permissions.index') with 'get' request.

routes/admin.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    // Permissions
    Route::resource('permissions', Admin\PermissionsController::class);
});
```

Admin\PermissionsController.php

```
public function update(PermissionRequest $request, Permission $permission): RedirectResponse
{
    $permission->update($request->validated());

    return to_route('admin.permissions.index')->with('success', 'Permission updated successfully.');
}
```

PermissionRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{
    $model = $this->route('role');

    return [
        'name' => [
            'sometimes',
            'required',
            'string',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique('permissions')->ignore($model->id ?? null),
        ],
    ];
}
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;
    root C:/www/example/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have noticed that the permission is updated but the error occurs during redirection.
Even if I perform the action without the validation, the same error occurs.

Here is my error:

[Laravel InertiaJs Redirection Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPiru.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464761/the-put-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-po)

Answer (score 0):

Your admin routes are located in a different file, and inertia-laravel by default, hooks up it's middleware only for the web routes:
https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup#middleware

In other words, either you need to move the routes to web.php, or judging by your setup, you need to configure you kernel, so Inertia is hooked up also with you admin routes. Something like this:

```
'admin' => [
// ...
\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
],
```